# fluent-bit TCP json parser for large integers pegged at 32bit maxint

Tags: json, fluent-bit

Given the following configuration file:

```
[INPUT]
    Name        tcp
    Listen      0.0.0.0
    Port        5170
    Format      json

[OUTPUT]
    Name        stdout
    Match       *
```

running fluent-bit on Windows and sending the string `{"key": 291000741888 }` the output is `[0] tcp.0: [1620860835.385804900, {"key"=>2147483647}]` (value is pegged at 32bit max int)

Is there a way to configure fluent-bit to deal with 64bit integers?

Comment: opened bug report: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/3481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was using `atol`.  For Windows cpp `long` is a 32-bit integer.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges.

This has been fixed by https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/pull/3501.